# How to stop scrolling div which is longer than window height?

Tags: css, sticky

Inside of #container (position:relative) I have 2 divs: both are 50% wide, the #first one is very tall (position:relative) and the #second one is at least 2000px tall.

Is there any way to make #second stop scrolling when it's bottom reached, but keep scrolling the other content? Would be great without making extra parent div for it.
Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Moor/ha4zybpb/

```css
#container{
    position:relative;
}
#first{
    width:50%;
    background:#333;
    height:10000px;
}
#second{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    width:50%;
    height:2000px;
    background:limegreen;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="first"></div>
    <div id="second"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you open to JS or jQuery solutions?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use [`position:sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) - although please be sure to check that the [browser compatability](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) for it meets your requirements.

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
#first{
    background:#333;
    display:inline-block;
    height:10000px;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:50%;
}
#second{
    background:linear-gradient(0deg,#f00,#090);
    bottom:0;
    display:inline-block;
    height:2000px;
    position:sticky;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"><div id="first"></div><div id="second"></div></div>
```

Comment: Holy Coyier, seems like I'm totally lost in time, I've never heard about they added this position. I'll test it out, but seems like it's not safe enough to use it now http://caniuse.com/#search=position%3Asticky

Answer (score 1):

A jquery "sticky" solution..

https://jsfiddle.net/cusjptLr/4/

```
var sh = $('#second').height();
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).innerHeight()) >= sh) {
   $('#second').addClass("sticky");
  }
});

#second.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  top: initial;
}
```

Comment: Hoped to avoid use scripts but seems like it's the only way. Thanks!

Comment: Hi@DemuriCelidze, can you pls check out this, i am implementing like this is now, i followed your rule, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335471/how-to-fix-right-div-image-and-scroll-left-div-text-content-in-bootstrap/50359199#50359199

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but it might help you on your way - 
check the scroll position and viewport height, and compare it to the height of the second element -

check this fiddle for my example. done with jquery

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dua77wyk/)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
var secondHeight = $('#second').height();
console.log(secondHeight);

var stopper = 0;

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    // Do something
  console.log(scroll+viewportHeight);



  if(secondHeight <= scroll+viewportHeight) {
  console.log('stop it here');
  stopper = 1;
  } else {
  stopper = 0;
  }
  console.log(stopper);

  if(stopper == 1) {
   $('#second').css('position','fixed');
   console.log('making it fixed');
  } else {
   $('#second').css('position','absolute');
   console.log('making it absolute');
  }


    });


});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting solution, will try it out.