# How to stop scrolling div which is longer than div height?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, sticky, scrollspy

I have image, aligning to right side and position is fixed and large text content which is aligning to left side. 
How the to do the image on the right side and text content should be only scroll able by using bootstrap. Here my code.

Thanks for your time and suggestions

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container" style="margin-top: 50px;">
  <div class="row pull-right" style=" width: 60%;float: right;"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random" alt="" width="1000px" height="1000px"></div>
  <div class="row pull-left" style=" width: 35%;float: left;"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.</p></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure, but, I guess, you can only accomplish this by sitting the `height` property of the two columns to a fixed number, for instance, `600px`. And then, use `overflow: scroll` for paragraph columns.

Give the two columns the  same height as the `img`, if you know the height of the `img` beforehand. Otherwise, use a `number` that you think fits well.

## Bootstrap-3

```css
.mt-10 {
  margin-top: 10rem;
}

.col-left,
.col-right {
  max-height: 600px;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container mt-10">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-left overflow-scroll">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus
        atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit,
        adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in
        unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam
        suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint
        ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus
        atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit,
        adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in
        unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam
        suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint
        ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus
        atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit,
        adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in
        unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-right">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000/?random" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erLMeW)

## Bootstrap-4

```css
.col-left,
.col-right {
  height: 600px;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-left overflow-scroll">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus
        atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit,
        adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in
        unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam
        suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint
        ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus
        atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit,
        adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in
        unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam
        suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint
        ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
        elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus
        atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit,
        adipisci, nobis illo est in unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero reiciendis accusamus atque expedita debitis reprehenderit, adipisci, nobis illo est in
        unde tempora fugit veniam suscipit voluptatibus sint ut sed amet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-right">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/600/?gravity=east" alt="" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvaLOL)