# How to style radio inputs both in checked and not checked state with different background?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, radio-button, bootstrap-4

I have multiple color select option, I want to highlight whatever they are selected

Here is my first image [image: first image],

Here I want to convert this to this [image: image below]

Thanks for time and suggestions

Comment: Are you sure they are `radio` inputs?. `Radio` input tend to have the same color.

Comment: @mahan, yes, you can find on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253920/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-radio-buttons

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the style of radio put likewise. For the checked state, use 
`[input-selector]:checked + label:after` and for the unchecked state, use `[input-selector]:not(:checked) + label:before`.

```css
[type="radio"]:checked,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked) {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #666;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:before,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after,
[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

[type="radio"]:not(:checked)+label:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
}

[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}


/* To change the background color, only customize the code below*/

.red-input:not(:checked)+label:before {
  background: red;
}

.red-input:checked+label:after {
  background: black;
}

.green-input:not(:checked)+label:before {
  background: green;
}

.green-input:checked+label:after {
  background: blue;
}

.black-input:not(:checked)+label:before {
  background: black;
}

.black-input:checked+label:after {
  background: silver;
}

.silver-input:not(:checked)+label:before {
  background: silver
}

.silver-input:checked+label:after {
  background: #E6B5A3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline m-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="mx-2">
      
    <input type="radio" id="test1" name="radio-group" class="red-input">
    <label for="test1">Peach</label>
   </div>
    <div class="mx-2">
    <input type="radio" id="test2" name="radio-group" class="green-input">
    <label for="test2">Orange</label>
   </div>
   <div class="mx-2">
    <input type="radio" id="test3" name="radio-group" class="black-input">
    <label for="test3">Mango</label>
   </div>
   <div class="mx-2">
    <input type="radio" id="test4" name="radio-group" class="silver-input">
    <label for="test4">Lime</label>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bMxRmE)

## Update

To set the default background of the inputs, use `[input-selector]:not(:checked)+label:before`.

```css
.red-input:not(:checked)+label:before {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi @mahan, how can i show on page load all their respectively color instead of white background?, on click just highlight as previous highlighted one

Comment: Updated the code and the codepen link too. Use `[input-slector]:not(:checked) + label:before`

Comment: Thanks a lot you are genius in css and bootstrap

Comment: can you do one more favour, i am working on bootstrap template, i am facing real issue like , can you please look at this once? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50335471/how-to-fix-right-div-image-and-scroll-left-div-text-content-in-bootstrap